# Encountering not defined error when calling function

Tags: javascript, laravel, web, es6-modules, javascript-import

I'm working on a API integration with the ES6 module system and jQuery. I want to use re-use my `addToCart` function, that is why I placed it into a separate file. But when calling it I get following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Export 'addToCart' is not defined in module`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should have the latest version of Node.js installed (or, at least 13.2.0+). Then do one of the following, as described in the documentation:

**Option 1**

In the nearest parent package.json file, add the top-level "type" field with a value of "module". This will ensure that all .js and .mjs files are interpreted as ES modules. You can interpret individual files as CommonJS by using the .cjs extension.

// package.json

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

**Option 2**

Explicitly name files with the .mjs extension. All other files, such as .js will be interpreted as CommonJS, which is the default if type is not defined in package.json.

Comment: no I'm using just pure es6 with no pkg.json file  that's a problem

Comment: then just change the file extension to .mjs

Comment: i resolved that it's exporting the var but not async function that's why I used first created the empty object at the top then add the method there and export that  moduleExports.addToFavourite = addToFavourite;
    moduleExports.updateHeaderCounts = updateHeaderCounts;
    moduleExports.addToCart = addToCart;